# How do I reinstall Windows 10 while also keeping my dual boot with Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, grub, ubuntu-14.04

My Windows has been acting up a lot lately and I want to reinstall it. However, I also want to keep my dual boot. I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10 64bit. I saw the thread about reinstalling Windows 7 while keeping dual boot, but that resolution requires a Windows 7 disc.
Ubuntu is on it's own partition, but Windows thinks it's empty(even though it definitely isn't). Windows Disk Management

It would be much appreciated if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Format C drive and install windows then repair grub it will work

Answer (score 0):

While not a full reinstall you could try doing a "factory reset" on Windows 10. This is under *Settings* > *Update & Security* > *Recovery*. Press the "Get Started" button for *Reset this PC*.

I recently had to do this for a VM that was acting up and it reset Windows 10 to a fresh install. But your mileage may vary based on what's wrong.

As far as I know this won't touch your boot partition.